# question about prefix and suffix in java

Tags: java, xml

I have an issue and i want your help!I have a specific REGEX which i have named it "unique" and i want to store the data that it gives me!! The prefix and the suffix of this regex!!so!!someone has told me to use

var prefix and

var suffix

but i don't know how to do it!

for your convinience i give u my xml for this regex

```
<reg name="unique">
<start><![CDATA[ <!-- 72 HOURS FORECASTS -->
]]></start>
<end><![CDATA[<!-- 72 HOURS FORECASTS -->]]></end>
</reg>
```

the code where i call this regex is

```
int k = 0;

for(Xml reg_is:fetchsite.child("site").child("regexps").children("reg")) {
    if(reg_is.string("name").contains("unique")){


        if(reg_is.child("start").content()=="")
            error += "\tNo prefix reg.exp. given.\n";

        else
              prefix = HtmlMethods.removeBreaks(replaceVariables(reg_is.child("start").content()));                     

        if(reg_is.child("end").content()=="")
            error += "\tNo suffix reg.exp. given.\n";
        else
                suffix = HtmlMethods.removeBreaks(replaceVariables(reg_is.child("end").content()));

    }
    else{
          poleis[k][0]= HtmlMethods.removeBreaks(reg_is.string("name"));
          poleis[k][1] = HtmlMethods.removeBreaks(replaceVariables(reg_is.child("start").content())); 
          poleis[k][2] = HtmlMethods.removeBreaks(replaceVariables(reg_is.child("end").content()));

           k++;
 }
```

Comment: ...Could you please, please format your post a bit? Capitalize the first letter of the first word in every sentence maybe... whitespace is your friend... don't just use two bangs and no space as your sole sentence delimiter... Anything?

Comment: Err... what? Can you share the code you're using now?

Comment: I'm very confused by your question.

Did you define a pattern inside a string named "unique"? Do you then want to apply this regex pattern to your data in order to find the prefix and suffix?

Could you be talking about the starting/ending position anchors?

Including ^ at the front of your patterns says it must match the start
Including $ at the end of your pattern says it must end

Finally, ]]> ]]> is NOT xml.

Comment: Where is your regex? Your xml code is basically just <reg><start></start><end></end></reg>. Also: What Regex syntax is this? Never seen XML encoded regular expressions like this.

Comment: @kate: Are you sure you know what a regular expression is? Because I don't think this question has anything to do with it at all.

Comment: yes it's a regex and it's an XML!! i want to take a specific html code so i give in my regex the start(meaning where to go and find it)
and the end(when to stop)
in the start and end i give it the html code which is nearer to the html code i want to store!!

Comment: @kate: Just because you can write in `if` without braces doesn't mean you should, it is better to always use braces.

Comment: @kate: Don't use `someString == ""`. Use `equals` for general `String` value comparison, `isEmpty()` in this particular scenario. Also, use lists instead of arrays. You won't even have to keep track of `k`, and you won't have to worry about possible reallocation in case the array is full. Invest an hour in learning about lists; it'll be way worth it in the long run.

Comment: Using == to check for String equality is *wrong*!!  Do this instead: reg_is.child("start").content().equals("") ... or even better: reg_is.child("start").content().isEmpty()

Comment: this code also compiles to me!! thanks  then but this is not my question!!i want to store this regex that i get!so someone told me to use var prefix and var suffix so how i should do this???i don't know

Comment: i don't want to store it in an array!!i have inly to things to store!ths start of my regex and the end!so i don't know what var is and i don't know who to do it

Comment: OK, but what do you want to do with the prefix and suffix?  Do you want to save them to a database?  Do you want to print them to the console?  Do you want to pass them to another method?

Comment: ok i want to store them in order with this regex as a base so i could find the other regex that i want to store to!! because this regex is like guidance for other regex so i could take the right data that i want!and this data to store them in an xml output!

Comment: How do you find the other regex that you want to store?  What regex are you looking for?

Comment: let me explain u my way of thinking! i want to get from an html page some data in order to upload them in my site!so i want this excact data!so i go to the html page and right before this data i find a regex that is unique for this lines and i declare it as a general regex and then i declare the other regex!my problem is not the other but the unique regex that i want to use it as a base in order to take the other regex!i want to save it but not with an array or a table

Comment: Ok, you don't want to save it in an array or table.  How *do* you want to save it?

Comment: i want to save it as var prefix var suffix but i don't know how to do it

Answer (score 1):

Some general comments on your code:

- Using == to check for `String` equality is ***wrong***!  Use the `equals()` method instead:

  ```
  reg_is.child("end").content().equals("")
  ```
- Also, if you're comparing a `String` variable to a hard-coded `String`, it's better to put the hard-coded String first.  That way, if the variable is null, your program won't throw a `NullPointerException` (because the hard coded `String` can never be null!)

  ```
  "".equals(reg_is.child("end").content())
  ```
- When doing a lot of `String` concatenation, it's more efficient to use a `StringBuilder`:

  ```
   StringBuilder error = new StringBuilder();
   error.append("\tNo prefix reg.exp. given.\n");
  ```
- Like Oscar Reyes said, the safe thing to do with if statements is *always use braces*.  If you add a line and forget to add the braces, you can waste *hours* tracking down bugs.  I know it's happened to me before...

  ```
  if(reg_is.child("start").content()==""){
    error += "\tNo prefix reg.exp. given.\n";
  } else {
    prefix = HtmlMethods.removeBreaks(replaceVariables(reg_is.child("start").content()));
  }
  ```

Comment: can you please help me with the store of this regex??? how i should use var prefix and var suffix??? and thanks for your advises